# How to embed video without Youtube or Vimeo?

Tags: video, youtube, html5-video, vimeo

Is it possible to embed a video on a website without it being placed on a Youtube, Vimeo or other alike services first?

I know about HTML5 Video tag, but if I understand it correctly it is not supported on all browsers at this point and when used needs Flash as a fall-back, which in its  turn is not supported by mobile. Or is it not a problem and all mobile supports HTML5?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers for a browser market share data, also HTML5 video tag is supported by Internet Explorer 9+, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari.

I would personally say it's pretty safe to use that tag nowadays, but you should go through the data and reach your own conclusion

Comment: Thank you!! I will read that article. Never had to deal with the VIDEO tag before, so was a bit uncertain about the best practices.